# HTML Partial View within Foreach

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

My index views in MVC contain a row per row set of actions like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SomeProperty)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top: -8px">
                <span class="fa fa-pencil" alt="Edit" />
            </a>
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: -8px">
                <span class="fa fa-info-circle" alt="Details" />
            </a>
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: -8px">
                <span class="fa fa--trash" alt="Delete" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </td>
}
```

There are other index pages where the 3 buttons will get reused so that already suggests a partial view just to save redundant code, the other part is I have to have the alt tag in the spans for 508 compliance so I want a partial view to help with consistency.

Problem is, if I just copy and paste the 3 buttons into a partial view, then I get "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context" and if I try to bring over the foreach, then I get more then one set of buttons in each row. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because `item` is a local variable in the loop. You could create a custom tag helper for the three buttons.

Comment: I know that it's a variable, I just don't know how to access it from a partial view. You could be right about the tag helper but I'm very wet behind the ears on those. Do you have any good examples I could learn from?

Comment: You could start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: `item` represents one element of the collection passed through the page's `Model`. So you would declare a new variable of the same type that `item` represents.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe is that your problem is related to the model which you didn't pass to the partial. There are some ways that you can pass your model to the partial view.

Think you have an Index view which has a model:

```
@model YourProjectNameSpace.Models.NameOfModel
......//Other HTML codes
```

when you want to call the partial view inside this view you should pass the model:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial",Model)
```

Also inside of your partial view, you need to add the following line in the beginning:

```
@model YourProjectNameSpace.Models.NameOfModel
```